# Error while consuming REST service in VC++

Tags: rest, visual-c++

I have used the below code to use as an example to consume the REST services in VC++. I am getting an error stating **"A Connection with the Server Could Not be Established"**. IIs version of my system is IIS 6.0. Please let me know what could be the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "http_client.h"
#include "filestream.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "sstream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "Windows.h"


using namespace utility;                    
using namespace web;                       
using namespace web::http;                 
using namespace web::http::client;         
using namespace concurrency::streams;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto fileStream = std::make_shared<ostream>();

    // Open stream to output file.
    pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("results.html")).then([=](ostream outFile)
    {
        *fileStream = outFile;

        // Create http_client to send the request.

            http_client client(U("http://www.bing.com/")); 
            uri_builder builder(U("/search"));
            builder.append_query(U("q"), U("Casablanca CodePlex"));
            return client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string());


        // Build request URI and start the request.


    })

        // Handle response headers arriving.
        .then([=](http_response response)
    {
        printf("Received response status code:%u\n", response.status_code());

        // Write response body into the file.
        return response.body().read_to_end(fileStream->streambuf());
    })

        // Close the file stream.
        .then([=](size_t)
    {
        return fileStream->close();
    });

    // Wait for all the outstanding I/O to complete and handle any exceptions
    try
    {
        requestTask.wait();
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        printf("Error exception:%s\n", e.what());
    }

    Sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the server running?

Comment: Yes..the server is running

Comment: I am not able to ping any URL or IP address. Is this the reason for getting the above error?

Comment: If you cannot ping the server there is no way you can connect to it. So first make ping work